# Rotate matrix Eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen

How to rotate 2d image stored in the Eigen matrix in a clockwise direction by 90 degrees?

My code:

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, n, n> m;
Eigen::Rotation2D rot(90);
auto m1 = m * rot.derived();
```

But I receive an error:

```
error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'ProductIsValid || SameSizes' "INVALID_MATRIX_PRODUCT"
```

Comment: `Eigen::Rotation2D` doesn't rotate a matrix. It moves a point in 2D space around origin (0, 0). `Eigen::Rotation2D` is 2x2 matrix, e.g. `(0 1; -1 0) * (2 1) = (1 -2)` is a rotation.

Comment: See http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt `R.transpose().colwise().reverse()`

Comment: @jabaa, technically, `Rotation2D` only behaves like a 2x2 matrix (when multiplying it). It is stored as a single scalar (with the angle in radians).

Comment: @chtz Yes, _"`Eigen::Rotation2D` is 2x2 matrix, ..."_ should be _"`Eigen::Rotation2D` behaves like a 2x2 matrix, ..."_. I wanted to simplify and oversimplified it :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate NxN Matrix Counter(anti)-Clockwise 90 Degress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839151/rotate-nxn-matrix-counteranti-clockwise-90-degress)

Answer (score 1):

Rotating **counter clockwise**,

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, n, n> m_rotated_ninty_ccwise = m.transpose().colwise().reverse();
```

Rotating **clockwise**,

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, n, n> m_rotated_ninty_cwise = m.reverse().transpose().reverse();
```